# How to use Random with 2d arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to put numbers on a 2d array by Randomizing the numbers. this is what i got so far but i keep getting 15 and i want it to go through each element in the array not one.

```
static Random random = new Random();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[,] array = new int[3, 5];
        FillArray(array);
        PrintArray(array);
    }

    public static void FillArray(int [ , ] arr)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < arr.GetLength(1); c++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < arr.GetLength(0); r++)
            {
                arr[r, c] = random.Next(15, 96);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PrintArray(int [,] arr)
    {
        WriteLine(arr.Length);
    }
```

Comment: What do you think `WriteLine(arr.Length);` does?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: The `Length` of the array is 15. That's why you see 15. If you want to print each element in an array, you have to write code to print each element in an array.

Comment: This question **should not** be closed - it is not "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error". This is a perfectly valid question. The OP is just a newbie who needs some simple help.

Answer (score 1):

`Random` is working as expected, though I think you might be confused about what `Array.Length` does

However, you can modify your `PrintArray` method to show your results

```
public static void PrintArray(int [,] arr)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < arr.GetLength(1); c++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < arr.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
             Console.Write(arr[r, c] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

[**Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OefDKb)

---

[Array.Length Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the total number of elements **in all the dimensions of the Array**.